# Get updated order after jQuery Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery UI's Sortable to reorder some list items. I would like to update the class of each li based on the updated order after sorting. Here is my html:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="1">apple</li>
    <li class="2">orange</li>
    <li class="3">pear</li>
    <li class="4">peach</li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to achieve is AFTER sorting pear above apple, my classes update like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="1">pear</li>
    <li class="2">apple</li>
    <li class="3">orange</li>
    <li class="4">peach</li>
</ul>
```

This JSFiddle is close to what I'm after, but I would like to update the class rather than the html: http://jsfiddle.net/4mcpq/3/

Answer (score 1):

As changing the position of one `li` would change the `class` of every other `li`, the only sane way to accomplish this is to iterate over the `li` elements on the `update` callback for `.sortable`:

```
    "update": function (event, ui) {
        $(this).children().each(function (i, elem) {
            var li = $(elem), // cache lookup
                cssClass = elem.className.split(' ').filter(function (name, i, array) {
                    return /^js[-]\d+$/g.test(name);
                }).join(''); // adding .join('') to transform to string
            // classes cannot start with a number (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner).
            // using pattern of "js-#" for the custom class
            $(elem).removeClass(cssClass).addClass('js-' + i);
        });
    }
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4mcpq/210/

A caveat: if you have thousands of `li` elements, this will likely slow your UI. There are much easier (and saner) ways to get the correct target `li` depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: do you think this solution is better than the answer I just entered? My solution seems to work for my needs, but is there a reason this solution would be better?

Comment: Your solution obviously works, and the only real difference between yours and mine is that I'm targeting the specific class to remove whereas your call to `.removeClass` with no classname specified removes all classes from the element, which may be detrimental in other ways. Overall, I am questioning the need for targeting classes when you could just grab the element using the `.index`, or the `.eq` methods. Also, which `li` do you need to process (the one being moved)? When does it need to be done?

Comment: It's a rather complex functionality. I have a Total Balance, then each li has an amount. I am going to subtract each li's amount from the Total Balance, starting with the first li (index[0]) after sorting. This will allow the user to determine which amount will be deducted first by sorting the order.

Comment: If you only need the first `li` after sort, just use `$('#sortable li:nth-child(1)')`, or `$('#sortable li:eq(0)')`, or `$('#sortable li').eq(0)`. If you're subtracting all of the `li` values from the total balance, then the order in which you're subtracting them shouldn't make a difference (`total - x - y - z === total - z - y - x`).

Comment: Well, I want to allow the user to determine the order of subtraction by sorting the fees. Say they have a $10,000 balance and 4 fees ($9000, $1000, $2000, $3000). The user can drag to the top which fee is paid first, then recalculate after sorting.

Comment: So you're always subtracting the first `li`, then the second, third (etc.), and always in sequential order? So you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/2f9vkhxj/9/

Comment: Yes, but a bit more complex.. I think I'm on the right track now though. @pete

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to update your question (as needed) and your answer (as needed) and accept either your own answer or one that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like nth-child() selector in your css.

For example:

```
#sortable li:nth-child(1) {
    /*insert your style for the first child here*/
}

#sortable li:nth-child(2) {
    /*insert your style for the second child here*/
}
```

Comment: I do not need to change the class to apply styling. I need to change the class to use in javascript logic, so this would not work in my case.

Comment: If you are using jquery, you can select the specific elements using the nth-child selector as well. For example $("#sortable li:nth-child(1)") for the first child.

Comment: This may work, but it would be so much simpler for me if I could just change the class. I do not know how many li's I will have, and I will be performing calculations for multiple fields in each li. This solution seems like it will over complicate the issue.

Comment: I see. An alternative is to iterate through the $("#sortable li") array, which is guaranteed to be in order, and change the class names that way. You can provide this functionality as the callback for the sortable's change or update event.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions and help. I went with another approach, but I'm sure your solution would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found I can use .index() to find the updated sort order. Then I can set the class of each li to it's index.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) { 
        $("#sortable li").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass(); 

            var $index = $(this).index();

            $(this).prop("class", $index);
        });    
    }
});
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2f9vkhxj/8/